# Recent Posts widget in Wordpress shows also drafts, private etc

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

Two hours spent searching an answer, but unsuccessfully.

The issue is next.
I've updated WP to latest version for one of my old Wordpress websites, and my standard recent posts widget is now showing all posts - publish, inherit, draft, revision and so on, instead of showing only "publish" posts.

I looked these files `class-wp-widget.php` and `class-wp-widget-recent-posts.php` but they are standard and shouldn't contain any bugs.
Maybe something is overriding standard behaviour, but I don't know how it's possible.
My website is pretty simple, doesn't contain any plugins (except "classic editor" and "classic widgets"). Disabling them change nothing.

`class-wp-widget-recent-posts.php` this file have next code which should do the work, but it doesn't work unfortunately.

```
apply_filters(
    'widget_posts_args',
    array(
        'posts_per_page'      => $number,
        'no_found_rows'       => true,
        'post_status'         => 'publish',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    ),
    $instance
)
```

For example, this row is working `'ignore_sticky_posts' => true` and when I change it's value to `false`, behaviour is changed.
But if I change this `'post_status' => 'publish'`, nothing changes and website is still show posts with ALL possible post statuses.

Any suggestions?

## UPDATE:

Fixed this editing `class-wp-widget-recent-posts.php` and added there one more parameter `'suppress_filters' => true`.
It's not the best solution, because this will be overwritten after next update, but now I don't know how to debug this and fix another way.

Comment: _"Maybe something is overriding standard behaviour, but I don't know how it's possible."_ - WordPress has this filter system, that allows plugins and themes to hook into stuff that is happening in other places. The code you have shown is already a part of that - it does not query the database here in that place, it only modifies the parameters that will be used in the database query happening elsewhere. So a similar thing could happen elsewhere in the code, overwriting any attempt of yours to modify the `post_status` parameter in this location somewhere later on.

Comment: How old was your WordPress? When you have to upgrade for more than 2 major releases it is advised to upgrade incrementally to avoid database damage.

[WordPress upgrade](https://wordpress.org/support/article/upgrading-wordpress-extended-instructions/#upgrading-across-multiple-versions)